# Use a bound client socket for making curl queries

Tags: c, sockets, curl

I am trying to implement a client in C, where want to bind it to a fixed port and make use of the obtained fd for in curl queries.
I want this fd not be closed, but to reuse same till the process lifetime, so that none other process can make use of the port, though the connection maybe closed.

Since the port shouldn't be used by any other process, I didn't use CURLOPT_LOCALPORT option.

Went though https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html for finding suitable curl options and found CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION and CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION

But when checked for the client port on server side, query was not made with fixed port.

Below is the code chunks which I tried before coming here.

```
//create socket
clientFd = socket(ipType, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//bind client socket
struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
clientAddr.sin_family = ipType;
clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(clientIP);
clientAddr.sin_port = clientPort;
bind(clientFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr))

//Using CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION
//Based on understanding, we need to make a connection to the server and return //back the fd
static curl_socket_t curl_opensocket(void *myFD, curlsocktype connType, struct curl_sockaddr *peerAddr) // connect to server using client FD
{
   struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)(&(peerAddr->addr));
   remAddr = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
   remPort = (u_short)addr_in->sin_port;
   inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), remAddr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

   sockfd = *(curl_socket_t *)myFD;

   connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)(&(peerAddr->addr)), sizeof(peerAddr->addr);
   return sockfd;
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, curl_opensocket);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, &clientFD);
```

Query with above option set, is choosing a different client port and fd is getting closed

```
//Using CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION
//Based on understanding, this gets called after socket creation and before connect

    static int sockopt_callback(void *clientp, curl_socket_t curlfd, curlsocktype purpose)
    {
        (void)clientp;
        (void)curlfd;
        (void)purpose;

        return CURLSOCKTYPE_IPCXN;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION, sockopt_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA, &clientFd);
```

Here too query is made with a different client port, but clientFd is not closed.

Please help me out, to use a binded fd in curl queries, where the connection can be terminated, but not the fd, and when fd is used in subsequent connections fixed port is chosen.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `CURLOPT_LOCALPORT`? It should do exactly what you want, and bind the socket to your requested port (if available).

Comment: 'Connection can be terminated, but not the fd' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I meant to say fd remains active, but established connection will be teared down, and the next query will be with a new connection, but using the same binded fd.
Please let me know my understanding is correct

Comment: @Bharath Once a socket connection is closed by either party, you cannot reuse the same fd to open a new connection (unless you are on Windows and use `ConnectEx()` and `DisconnectEx()` to reuse `SOCKET` handles). On most platforms, you must create a new fd for each new connection. You will just have to bind them to the same local port, which is what `CURLOPT_LOCALPORT` does for you. But, for what you are attempting, you will probably have to enable `SO_REUSE_(ADDR|PORT)` on each fd, and not close an older fd before binding a newer fd, to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking your time to help me.
@Remy Lebeau : Thanks for the improving my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In your "CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION" you should return   CURL_SOCKOPT_ALREADY_CONNECTED instead of CURLSOCKTYPE_IPCXN, as your socket is already connected.

Check the example code given here
https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.html